# Two Top Economist getting 9/10 correct

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that we now have twenty economists instead of just one, each of whom makes their predictions based
on the toss of a fair coin. what is the probability that the second most successful
of the twenty economists will be right at least 9 times out of the next 10 predictions they make?

(To clarify: in this question, if the top two most successful economists make the same number
of correct predictions, each of them will also be considered as the second most successful one.
For example, if two or more guess correctly all 10 times out of 10, this will mean, in particular,
that the second most successful economist guessed correctly 10 times out of 10.)

I've made some progress on this problem but I want to be careful because I want to get it right. The probability for a single individual to get 9/10 right is 0.0107421875. Using this, the probability that the most successful of these economists will be right is 0.194269554291. Now i found it tricky in calculating the second of these gets 9/10 right. I assume it should be a lower percentage for two to get at least 9/10 right than just getting one. I think I'm so close but I need help with that final push.

Comment: You want to compute the probability that at least 2 are right 9/10 times. Assuming that the economists are independent, it is sufficient to compute the probability that one person gets at least 9/10, and use the binomial distribution.

Comment: thanks, I cant believe I didn't think of that since I didn't use the binomial distribution to solve no one getting 9/10

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  For this question, the important thing is the probability that an individual scores $9/10$.  You need to ignore the rest. If it is a coin flip, that chance is $p=\frac {11}{1024}$  Now the chance that the second doesn't get $9/10$ is $1-$ (the chance that at most one gets $9/10$ right)

Answer (score 0):

probability that second most accurate gets at least 9 = probability that at least two get at least 9 = 1 - (probability that fewer than two get at least 9) = 1 - (probability that none get 9 + probability that exactly one gets 9)

If $p$ is the probability that a particular economist gets 9, then

probability that none get 9 = $(1-p)^{20}$

probability that exactly one gets 9 = $20p(1-p)^{19}$

The last number is derived from the fact that the one who gets 9 had probability $p$, the nineteen that didn't had probability $(1-p)$, and there were $20$ choices for who would get 9.